# List pages by custom field?

Tags: pages, list

For SEO purposes I use my URLs like this:

site.com/parent/child/

Currently I have pages like this:

> site.com/parent/
>
> site.com/page-1/
>
> site.com/page-2/
>
> site.com/page-3/

I want to list **some** of those page-1, page-2 etc. pages on site.com/parent/
I thought the best way to do this is to add a custom field to those.

So is there a better way to do this?
If not, how can I wp list pages based on custom fields?

Answer (score 1):

Function `wp_list_pages()` accepts arguments from `get_pages()` function. To list pages filtered by custom field use `meta_key` and `meta_value` in parameters array. A list of accepted parameters can be found [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_pages/) and [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/).

```
wp_list_pages([
    'meta_key' => 'your_meta_KEY',
    'meta_value' => 'searched_value', // optional
]);
```

`meta_value` is not mandatory, if you skip it, a list of pages with any value of the custom field will be returned.

Comment: I will try it later (i am not at my PC now). TY